# Elimination reaction

Tags: reaction-mechanism

In this question i understand that we have to break C- N bond. But which one to choose?[image]

Comment: If the question has been sufficiently answered, please accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of **Cope Elimination** where the base takes up hydrogen from the least sterically hindered Carbon atom to avoid crowding in the Transition state. Hence, Hoffman Alkene is obtained and **ethene** is formed.

The reaction is not an example of E1cb since the Leaving Group is a stable alkene whereas the basic requirement for a reaction to be categorised as E1cb is that the leaving group should be a weak base.